# Issue with EJB Code - Stateful Session Bean + Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0, java-ee-6

I am trying to learn Ejb now. Can anybody help me how to implement [this Stateful Session Bean Example](http://www.roseindia.net/ejb/example-of-statelfulbean.shtml) by using [this Hibernate example](http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/firstexample.shtml). Thanks in advance.

NB: Actually I want simple code adding those two examples for understanding whole thing how it works. Thanks.

Comment: A tutorial which uses scriptlets in JSP and doesn't indent code correctly is a bad tutorial. Learn from somewhere else, like http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/ for example.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I want a simple example code to understand properly how jsp-ejb(stateful session beans)-hibernate works.I am not finding any where a example code implementing those. Can any body help me by giving an example code implementing those.